# hadoop pipe compilation error

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I tried Hadoop Pipe (WordCount) for the first time and got the following errors during compilation:

```
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /root/hadoop-0.20.205.0/c++/Linux-amd64-64/lib/libhadooppipes.a when searching for -lhadooppipes
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lhadooppipes  
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /root/hadoop-0.20.205.0/c++/Linux-amd64-64/lib/libhadooputils.a when searching for -lhadooputils
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lhadooputils
```

Does this mean that I need to get Hadoop source tar and then compile in some fashion? Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Can you post your Makefile?

One thing that fixed my problem was I had a -m32 flag that needed to be changed to -m64.

Make sure that you check your flags because chances are that your compiler is getting confused about the architecture.

Comment: thanks but I gave up using hadoop pipe since this post. If I try again next time, I will revisit this posting.